# How to use Selection.Find in Word's Drawing object textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to find all occurences of certain words in a Word document and erase it but for a reason I don't know, it doesn't erase the words that are in textboxes.

(Note: these are Drawing object textboxes, inserted from a Building Block.)

Here is my code:

```
Dim myRange As Range

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    myRange.WholeStory
    myRange.Select

    With objWord.Selection.Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Text = arr(i)
                        .Replacement.Text = ""
                        .Forward = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .MatchWholeWord = False
                        .MatchWildcards = False
                        .MatchSoundsLike = False
                        .MatchAllWordForms = False
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Next i
```

I tried to add a bit of code to search through the shapes of the word document because I saw it online but it didn't work either.

It looked like this:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim shp As Shape

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    myRange.WholeStory
    myRange.Select
    With objWord.Selection.Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Text = arr(i)
                        .Replacement.Text = ""
                        .Forward = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .MatchWholeWord = False
                        .MatchWildcards = False
                        .MatchSoundsLike = False
                        .MatchAllWordForms = False
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With


For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        shp.Select
        With Selection.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = arr(i)
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    End If
Next


Next i
```

Comment: I didn't create the word doc. I'm working with PDF file converted to word documents sent by users. These text boxes were created with the conversion process of adobe acrobat.

Comment: I'm using excel vba and working with a word document

Comment: @CindyMeister actually i just noticed i copy-pasted the wrong test that i did. It was supposed to be `BuildingBlockEntries(" Simple Text Box")`. Also, sorry to double up on the response there

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Not a problem :-) Together with the picture from the OP it led me to the important info. Which of the at least four different kinds of text box in Word came in question. They're all totally different when it comes to this question!

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of text boxes are *Drawing objects*, so your attempt using the `Shapes` collection was a good start. In order to get to the text range inside a Shape (drawing object) you need the `Shape.TextFrame.TextRange` property.

I've "tweaked" the code you posted to work from outside of Word:

- I fully qualified the Word objects; in order to use the code as it stands it requires a reference to the Word object library in the VBA project.
- I've qualified the Word `ActiveDocument` object with the Word application variable `objWord`
- I've substituted your `Range` object (myRange) for `Selection.Find` and set that to the entire body of the Word document
- I changed the `Find.Wrap` setting to `wdFindStop` because `wdFindContinue` is very dangerous in VBA (it can go into an infinite loop)

This should get you going.

```
Sub FindInTextBoxes()
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim shpRange As Word.Range
    Dim objWord as Word.Application

    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    'Assumes the document is already open in Word

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Set myRange = objWord.ActiveDocument.Content
        With myRange.Find
                            .ClearFormatting
                            .Text = arr(i)
                            .Replacement.Text = ""
                            .Forward = True
                            .wrap = wdFindStop
                            .MatchCase = False
                            .MatchWholeWord = False
                            .MatchWildcards = False
                            .MatchSoundsLike = False
                            .MatchAllWordForms = False
                            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With


        For Each shp In obWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If shp.Type = Office.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
                Set shpRange = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                With shpRange.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = arr(i)
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```